# python ctypes structure pointers don't resolve as expected

Tags: python, ctypes, libxml2

I've built a ctypes interface to Libxml2, the Python xmlDoc is:

```
class xmlDoc(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("_private",ctypes.c_void_p),   #    application data
        ("type",ctypes.c_uint16),       #    XML_DOCUMENT_NODE, must be second !
        ("name",ctypes.c_char_p),       #    name/filename/URI of the document
        ("children",ctypes.c_void_p),   #    the document tree
        ("last",ctypes.c_void_p),       #    last child link
        ("parent",ctypes.c_void_p),     #    child->parent link
        ("next",ctypes.c_void_p),       #    next sibling link
        ("prev",ctypes.c_void_p),       #    previous sibling link
        ("doc",ctypes.c_void_p),        #    autoreference to itself End of common part
        ("compression",ctypes.c_int),   #    level of zlib compression
        ("standalone",ctypes.c_int),    #    standalone document (no external refs) 1 if standalone="yes" 0 if sta
        ("intSubset",ctypes.c_void_p),  #    the document internal subset
        ("extSubset",ctypes.c_void_p),  #    the document external subset
        ("oldNs",ctypes.c_void_p),      #    Global namespace, the old way
        ("version",ctypes.c_char_p),    #    the XML version string
        ("encoding",ctypes.c_char_p),   #    external initial encoding, if any
        ("ids",ctypes.c_void_p),        #    Hash table for ID attributes if any
        ("refs",ctypes.c_void_p),       #    Hash table for IDREFs attributes if any
        ("URL",ctypes.c_char_p),        #    The URI for that document
        ("charset",ctypes.c_int),       #    Internal flag for charset handling, actually an xmlCharEncoding
        ("dict",ctypes.c_void_p),       #    dict used to allocate names or NULL
        ("psvi",ctypes.c_void_p),       #    for type/PSVI information
        ("parseFlags",ctypes.c_int),    #    set of xmlParserOption used to parse the document
        ("properties",ctypes.c_int),    #    set of xmlDocProperties for this document set at the end of parsing
    ]
```

The char* pointers all make sense, the xmlNode* and xmlDoc* don't, the xmlDoc->doc should point to the same location (*from VS Code*):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in my own code, which came from the *ctypes* templates.  Effectively, the template cast `ctypes.c_void_p` to a `ctypes.POINTER()`, which in this case is my structure definition of the `xmlNode`.  The line of code is:

```
#   perfect use of lambda
xmlNode = lambda x: ctypes.cast(x, ctypes.POINTER(LibXml.xmlNode))
```

for the fixed code:

```
def InsertChild(tree: QTreeWidget, item: QTreeWidgetItem, node: ctypes.c_void_p):
   cur = node.contents
   xmlNode = lambda x: ctypes.cast(x, ctypes.POINTER(LibXml.xmlNode))
   while cur:
      item.setText(0, cur.name.decode('utf-8'))
      # if cur.content: item.setText(1, cur.content.decode('utf-8'))
      item.setText(2, utils.PtrToHex(ctypes.addressof(cur)))
      if cur.children: 
         child = QTreeWidgetItem(tree); 
         item.addChild(child); 
         InsertChild(tree, child, xmlNode(cur.children))
      if cur.next: 
         cur = xmlNode(cur.next)
         item = QTreeWidgetItem(tree);
      else: cur = None
   return
```